# grunt-contrib-connect on same port as node.js

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs

I'm using [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) as it comes with [Yeoman's angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular).

I also have a node.js express app with a jade view in which I want to reference .js, .css, .html but it seems like grunt-contrib-connect and express cannot share the same port.

In my jade view:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='styles/main.css')
```

In my grunt.js:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000, 
    hostname: 'localhost'
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          lrSnippet,
          mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
          mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
```

In my app.js:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

If I change this port to 9000 I can only get static files served by grunt-contrib-connect and no resources of the express application.

**Can you get grunt-contrib-connect and node.js to play nicely together on the same port?**

Comment: No process can listen in the same port as another process.

Comment: Ok, good to know :) New idea, does this sound possible: some kind of proxy which routes to different ports dependent on if you go to `/` or `/static` ?

Comment: See posted answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start a proxy via the [bouncy](https://npmjs.org/package/bouncy) package:

```
var bouncy = require('bouncy');

var server = bouncy(function (req, res, bounce) {
    if (req.headers.host === 'cdn.example.com') {
        bounce(gruntConnectPort);
    } else if (req.headers.host === 'example.com') {
        bounce(expressPort);
    } else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end('no such host');
    }
});
server.listen(anotherPort);
```

Feel free to adapt it, if it fits for you.

Comment: I did not really try bouncy but tried httpProxy instead which worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're end goal is but I'm thinking that you really just have one web app, powered by Yeoman, in which you'd like to use something like Express to render Jade views.  If this is the case I'd check out [David Moro's guide](http://davidemoro.blogspot.com/2013/08/yeoman-express-and-angularjs.html) for updating a project that was created with Yeoman's Angular Generator to use Express for a server.

I used this when I wanted to update my site from static pages to something that could also use server side templating.  With this setup you'll no longer use Connect during development, but instead use Express for everything.  Make sure to check check out his GitHub link to make sure that you get all of the changes that he made.